# Send an image through XML from android

Tags: java, android, xml, image

I do need to send an image in android selected by the user to a servlet. I do already have the selected images path in `selectedImagePath` variable. Now, I need to send that image along with some other information to the server. What I have done is:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
int height = image.getHeight();
int width = image.getWidth();
int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
image.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

My idea is to send the color values in the `pixel` array as comma separated string through XML. I think `Integer.toHexString` will be of helpful.  For example:

```
<width>300</width>
<height>400</height>
<data>0xffffff,0xff00ff,0xffff00,...</data>
```

At the server side, decode the color values and create a `BufferedImage` and then save it to the file system using `ImageIO.write`.

Now, my question is:

- Is it the correct way to do this?
- Is there any other better and efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you encode the image to Base64 format for easy transfer in text based way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step-1** convert your bitmap image to byte array

**Step-2** encode the byte[] to Base64 and send

Thanks